# initialize $scope variable using $resource and $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to initialise a Angualr scope variable using a function that calls resource.query() from service and its returning empty.

Below is my code

Controller

```
$scope.categories = _processedCategories($scope.excludedCategories);

// excluded categories is an array of objects
function _processedCategories(excludedCategories) {
    preDefinedCategoryService.rest.query({},
        function (data) {
            categories = _.filter(data._embedded.categories, function (n) {
                return (n.id !== excludedCategories.id);
            });    
            return categories
        },
        function () {
            console.log ('error');
        });    
   }
```

I am getting $scope.categories empty, but when I `$scope.categories = _.filter(..)` instead, it populate them directly. I know its something related to `$promise` but how to resolve it according to my requirement? Becase I want to reuse this function later aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return from asynchronous operation. Use Promise API to provide a callback to be invoked when data is loaded and processed:

```
_processedCategories($scope.excludedCategories).$promise.then(function(categories) {
    $scope.categories = categories;
});

// excluded categories is an array of objects
function _processedCategories(excludedCategories) {
    return preDefinedCategoryService.rest.query({}, function (data) {
        return categories = _.filter(data._embedded.categories, function (n) {
            return (n.id !== excludedCategories.id);
        });
    }, function () {
        console.log('error');
    });
}
```

Note, that `_processedCategories` now returns result of `preDefinedCategoryService.rest.query` function invocation, which is promise object.